# I thought only moderators could close questions with one vote. Has this changed recently?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23617190/335858) as a duplicate, and then... it got closed right away!

### marked as duplicate by dasblinkenlight 3 mins ago

Not that I'm complaining - I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate, but I didn't expect the question to get closed just like that. Did I miss an announcement, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: You have superpowers now!